# How to think about representation upto homotopy of Lie algebroids

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebroids

This is about the notion of representations upto homotopy of Lie algebroids. I am following the reference [Representations up to homotopy of Lie algebroids](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.0319.pdf) by Camilo Arias Abad and Marius Crainic.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $A\rightarrow M$ a Lie algebroid over $M$. The proposition $3.2$ in above mentioned paper says that a representation upto homotopy is given by the following data:

- a graded vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ (I think they are considering $\mathbb{Z}$ grading $E=\oplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}E^i$),
- a degree $1$ operator $\partial :E\rightarrow E$ making $(E,\partial)$ a complex (with $\partial:E^i \rightarrow E^{i+1}$),
- an $A$-connection on $E\rightarrow M$ (a nice map $\nabla:\Gamma(M,A)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$) that is compatible with the complex structure $\partial:E\rightarrow E$,
- and $\rm{End}(E)$-valued $2$-form $\omega_2$ of **total degree $1$**, i.e., $$\omega_2\in \Omega^2(A, \underline{\rm{End}}^{-1}(E))$$ satisfying the condition $\partial(\omega_2)+R_\nabla=0$, where $R_\nabla$ is the curvature of $\nabla$,
- for each $i>2$ and $\rm{End}(E)$-valued $i$-form $\omega_i$ of **total degree $1$**, i.e., $$\omega_i\in \Omega^i(A,\underline{\rm{End}}^{1-i}(E))$$
  satisfying the condition $\partial(\omega_i)+d_\nabla(\omega_{i-1})+\omega_2\wedge\omega_{i-2}+\cdots+\omega_{i-2}\wedge\omega_2=0$.

The question is as I mentioned in the title: how should one think about representations upto homotopy?

Representation of a Lie algebroid $A\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$, together with ''an action'' of $A\rightarrow M$ on $E\rightarrow M$. I used the term action to remember (and relate) the notion of representation of a Lie group/Lie algebra etc. Here, the "action" is the data of a map
$$\nabla:\Gamma(M,A)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$$
that is nice to some extent; precisely, we want $\nabla$ to be a flat $A$-connection. The curvature $R_\nabla$ would then be zero. This is what I understand about representations of Lie algebroids.

The punch line I heard multiple times is, representation upto homotopy of a Lie algebroid $A\rightarrow M$ is a graded vector bundle with an $A$-connection that is flat upto some correction.

So, the first three conditions are understandable. The third condition says, the curvature $R_\nabla$ may not be zero, but there is a $2$-form $\omega_2$ with $\partial(\omega_2)+R_\nabla=0$.

If the degrees of $\omega_2, \omega_{i-2}$ matches appropriately, then we would just have $\omega_2\wedge \omega_{i-2}+\omega_{i-2}\wedge\omega_2=0$. Assuming this is the case for each component in $4$th condition, we would have $\partial(\omega_i)+d_\nabla(\omega_{i-1})=0$. But, the degrees may not match that well to give us  $\partial(\omega_i)+d_\nabla(\omega_{i-1})=0$. The condition $\partial(\omega_i)+d_\nabla(\omega_{i-1})=0$ is still fine. But, the condition $$\partial(\omega_i)+d_\nabla(\omega_{i-1})+\omega_2\wedge\omega_{i-2}+\cdots+\omega_{i-2}\wedge\omega_2=0$$ is too difficult to digest. How should one think about this condition?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes. Fixed it. many thanks :)

Comment: Most likely this relates to the [Maurer-Cartan forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form#On_a_homogeneous_space): the equation for them is $d\omega+\omega\wedge\omega=0$; here it seems to be satisfied with $d=\partial+d_\nabla$...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that could possibly be true.. If you come up with some more explanation, please add it here...

Comment: One way to think about this is by considering the (algebroid) differential forms valued in $E$: $\Omega^{\bullet}(E)$. Recall that for a vector bundle $E$, a connection on $E$ is equivalent to a degree $1$ operator $d$ on $\Omega^{\bullet}(E)$. The curvature is given by $d^2$, so that the connection is flat precisely when $d^2 = 0$. In this case, $\Omega^{\bullet}(E)$ is a **dg module** over the dg algebra of Lie algebroid forms.

Comment: When $E$ is a graded vector bundle, we may still consider $\Omega^{\bullet}(E)$. It has a total grading that combines the form degree and the grading on $E$. We can still try to equip it with a differential $d$, turning it into a dg module. But now this no longer corresponds to a flat connection on $E$. Instead, it is a representation up to homotopy. 
So I believe that all the conditions involving $\partial$, $d_{\nabla}$, and $\omega_{i}$, all combine into the single equation $d^2 = 0$.

Comment: @unknownymous can you please make it as an answer (if you can also add some references)

Comment: The references for my comment are Propositions 2.3 and Definition 3.1 in the reference you give. In fact, Proposition 3.2 which you cite is the converse of what I said.

Comment: Another place to look for intuition is the notion of a pseudo-functor between $2$ (or higher) categories, where the usual equation $F(f \circ g) = F(f) \circ F(G)$ does not hold on the nose, but only up to coherent isomorphisms. Related to this, maybe you would find it useful to look at RUTHs of groupoids, and integrations of algebroid RUTHs. Abad and collaborators have plenty of nice papers about these things.